# Updating 2 variables in ajax-request by one click(rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

i make a ajax-request to the server, which responds me with JSON.

My js.file when on the success :

```
success: function(data){
   //was disliked
   if ($(_this).hasClass( "disliked" )){
   $(_this).removeClass("disliked").addClass("liked");
   dislike_action.text(data.post_dislikes);
   $(_this).text(data.post_likes);
 }
```

my respond from the controller :

```
render json: { post_likes: @post.likes_count, post_dislikes: @post.dislikes_count }
```

the problem is, that it changes just post_dislike:

```
        $(_this).text(data.post_likes);
```

but not the both:

```
dislike_action.text(data.post_dislikes);
$(_this).text(data.post_likes);
```

To see the change of the post_dislikes i have to reload the page, so where is the problem ?

Here's my full js file:

```
var dislike_action = $(".dislike_action");
var like_action = $(".like_action");

$(function(){  
  var dislikes_count = $(".dislikeAction").text();
  var likes_count = $(".likeAction").text();
  $(".likeAction").click(function(){
      var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
      var _this = this
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(data){
          //was disliked
          if ($(_this).hasClass( "disliked" )){
            $(_this).removeClass("disliked").addClass("liked");
            dislike_action.hide();
            $(_this).text(data.post_likes);
          }//was neither liked nor disliked
          else {           
            $(_this).addClass("liked").text(data.post_likes);
          }
        },
        error: function(data){
          alert(data.responseText);
          console.log(data); 
        }
      });
    });

  $(".dislikeAction").click(function(){
      var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
      var _this = this
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/dislike',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(data){
          //was liked
          if ($(_this).hasClass( "liked" )){
            $(_this).removeClass("liked").addClass("disliked");
            like_action.text(data.post_likes);
            $(_this).text(data.post_dislikes);
          }//was neither liked nor disliked
          else {           
            $(_this).addClass("disliked").text(data.post_dislikes);
          }
        },
        error: function(data){
          alert(data.responseText); 
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without seeing your html but it looks like your problem may be from having two different classes for each like and dislike.

You have this declared at the top

```
var dislike_action = $(".dislike_action");
var like_action = $(".like_action");
```

But then

$(".dislikeAction") and $(".likeAction") used everywhere else

I think if you change the declaration at the top to this ...

```
var dislike_action = $(".dislikeAction");
var like_action = $(".likeAction");
```

It may work

Comment: no, it's not working. I still need to reload the page to see the decremented value